# jQuery AJAX and progress of multiple queries

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

One of the functionalities of the system I'm building may result in running many complex queries, sometimes as many as 100 or more.

So in a nutshell the process is:
on *screen1.php* user ticks a bunch of boxes to select the records he wants to be acted upon. When clicked submit this goes to *screen2.php* where user is given a list of selected items, and options to confirm selection, go back and edit selection and cancel the whole process.

Now if he presses the confirm button,  jquery will execute ajax call to *process.php* file where all the processing is happening.

As I said this may be a lengthy process and because of this I want the user to know the progress. I played with the buffer flushing to output results as they happen for the past 2 days, but it simply would not work, so I gave up and took a different approach.

I created a table called transaction_progress with fields:
[ID] [userID] [totalJobs] [completedJobs]

to which at the beginning of the *process.php* file I write the id of the user calling the process, and the total number of queries that will be happening (I know this because of how many ID were selected), for example 60:

```
INSERT INTO transaction_progress VALUES (0123456,60,0)
```

Next as all selected ID are acted upon in a loop, and after each query is successfully processed I run a quick update query for the transaction_progress table:

```
UPDATE transaction_progress SET completedJobs+1 WHERE userID=0123456
```

In that way by reading that table I get an idea where the processing is at the moment.

Now, here is where I am stuck: once I call the *process.php* file via jQuery AJAX how do I start reading the transaction_progress table every, lets say 5 seconds, to get the current progress?

Comment: Fire another ajax request every 5 seconds `setInterval()` to read `transaction_progress`

Comment: You want to read every 5 seconds in PHP on backend or to show progress to user and to do status requests using jQuery?

Comment: @Daan - can you give me an example of how would you implement 2 ajax calls in one  $(document).on('click','#btn_Confirmed', function() {})  statement. Thanks

Comment: @user3818264 That's a little too broad for stackoverflow.